# WebView in fragment vertical scroll issue

Tags: android, webview

I have a `WebView` in a Fragment. Sometimes when I scroll down, the view goes up and vice versa. 
My code to load WebView is:

```
webView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);


webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        getActivity().setTitle("Loading...");
        getActivity().setProgress(progress * 100);
        if(progress == 100)
           getActivity().setTitle("2Mummy");
        }
});

webView.loadUrl("http://my_url_here");

webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                && webView.canGoBack()) {
           handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
           return true;
        }
        return false;
     }
});

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        if ((webView.canGoBack()) || (url!=url)){

        }
        else{

        }
        return false; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
         webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

});
webView.scrollTo(0,webView.getContentHeight());
```

And my fragment xml is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/categoriesfrag"
    tools:context="com.quadcircles.tomummy.Fragment.Categories">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"/>
```

When I load the site from my phone, it scrolls perfectly, issue comes up when I load the same site in `WebView`.
Your suggestions are appreciated

Comment: check with relativelayout

Comment: give orientation  vertical for your LinearLayout